# AngularJS nested functions in services and dependency injection?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Ok I have two modules which depend upon each other both modules have services, directives, ctrl's etc, now my question is how do i get values assigned in the nested function of the second module's service in the controller of the first service, I have added the dependencies to the first controller but i can't see to get at the nested functions variables to then manipulate them in the ctrl of the first module here's the code(considerably cut down):

```
        angular.module("mainapp", [
                "dateSheet",
                "bookingApp"
            ]).controller("AppCtrl", [
                    "$scope",
                    "$attrs",
                    "Booking",
                     function (scope, source, attributes, AppDataLoader, booking, Booking) {
                        //HERE I NEED TO BE ABLE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS

                           var getdaiyrate = function(){
                          var dumpDailyRates = scope.Booking.getalldates.getrates.dailyPrice 
                          console.log(dumpDailyRates);
                            }

                     }
]);
    angular.module("bookingApp", ["bookingApp.services",]);
    angular.module("bookingApp.services").service("Booking", [
        function(){
                function getRate(source, dateSheet, dateSheetCtrl, expect, $$childTail, appData) {
                                var dateValue = $("Date", source).text() || "";
                                if (!dateValue) {
                                    return null;
                                }
                                var dailyPrice = $("DailyPrice", source).text() || "";
                                var weeklyPrice = $("WeeklyPrice", source).text() || "";
                                var monthlyPrice = $("MonthlyPrice", source).text() || "";
                                var isAvailable = $("IsAvailable", source).text() === "1";
                                var minimumStay = Number($("MinimumStay", source).text());
                                if (isNaN(minimumStay)) {
                                    minimumStay = DEFAULT_MINIMUM_STAY;
                                }
                                return {
                                    date: new Date(dateValue),
                                    dailyPrice: dailyPrice,
                                    weeklyPrice: weeklyPrice,
                                    monthlyPrice: monthlyPrice,
                                    reserved: !isAvailable,
                                    minimumStay: minimumStay
                                };
                            }
                            return {
                            getalldates: function(source, $scope){
                                return getRate(source, scope);
                                }

                            };
                }
            ]);
```

The above doesn't work what am i doing wrong.... 
Could someone please send me in the direction of a decent tutorial that deals with a end to end app using various modules and dependencies?? 
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the service module into the module that you want to use it in. So the first line becomes

```
angular.module("mainapp", ["dateSheet","bookingApp","bookingApp.services"])
```

Also i don't see the creation of `bookingApp.services` so this may also be required

```
angular.module("bookingApp.services",[]);
```

and the invocation would be something like this

```
var dumpDailyRates = Booking.getalldates(sourceParameter, $scope);
```

Comment: @Chandermai thank you  I'm still having trouble  with the invocation though I'm doing this: 
`   return {
                getalldates: function(dailyPrice, source, scope){
                    return getRate(source, scope);
                    },`
Then this in my call: 
scope.getdatesall = function(){
                    var dumpDailyRates = scope.Booking.getalldates(source, scope, dailyPrice);
                    var dumpDailyRatesnew = dumpDailyRates.dailyPrice;
                    console.log(dumpDailyRates);
                    }; 
Cannot call method 'getalldates' of undefined

Comment: Can you put your script code in a fiddle so that i can understand.

Comment: of Course but it's large i'm refractoring it beacuse of just this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/PEBRN/1/
the line with the xml binding to the dom is  line 869 - 932 and the main is at at the top line 16 - 65

Comment: The service Booking is available in the function parameters so you dont need to use `scope.Booking`, i have updated the answer

Comment: this still fails to work... I'm trying this: scope.dumpDailyRates = function(scope, source){
                       var getallofthis = Booking.getalldates(scope, source);
                       var dumdumdum = getallofthis.dailyPrice;
                       console.log(dumdumdum); 
                    };

Comment: Update you fiddle with the changes you have done, there is no property defined as getRate, how are you using it like property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34992/discussion-between-vimes1984-and-chandermani)